# Android client application doesn't show the server answer properly/

Tags: java, android, client-server

I've been struggling the whole day to make an Android client application. I managed to get the answer from the server but i can't properly display it in a text View. I did the app using other answers from here or Youtube videos.

The application should be really simple.Then i press a button, it sends a SQL query to the server and it returns some data from the database which should be displayed in a text View.

I'll post the code and then explain where the problem occurs:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

private TextView serverMessage;
private Thread thread;
private Socket clientSocket;
private String mesaj;
String answer = "";
String partial = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    serverMessage = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textView));


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void Start(View v)
{
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket("92.55.154.98", 100);
                Log.d("Sending server", "SEnding    " + "SELECT * FROM Pubs");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println("SELECT * FROM Pubs");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                while ((partial = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer= answer + partial +"\n" ;
                    Log.e("In while", answer);
                }
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                Log.e("After while", answer);
                Message answer = null;
                answer.obj=answer;
                handler.sendMessage(answer);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    thread.start();
    answer="";
    //serverMessage.setText(answer);

}

Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public  void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {    Log.w("Message recieved ?? ", msg.obj.toString());
        messageDisplay(msg.obj.toString());

    }
};

public void messageDisplay(String mesaj)
{
    serverMessage.setText(mesaj);
}
}
```

The problem appears here in the Start method:

```
                while ((partial = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer= answer + partial +"\n" ;
                    Log.e("In while", answer);
                }
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                Log.e("After while", answer);
```

The log properly shows me the answer String just inside the while loop. After the while loop ends, nothing else from this method runs. It doesn't display the log that i placed after the while loop Log.e("After while", answer); I managed to show the second log just if i closed the server, but it crashed when it tried to run the rest of the code.

The result is somehow showed if i uncomment this part that's at the end of the Start method:

```
 thread.start();
    answer="";
    //serverMessage.setText(answer);
```

In this case he result is only showed if i press the button twice !

Does anybody have an ideea why it acts like that and is there a solution ?

Comment: `After the while loop ends`. No it does not end. It sticks in the while loop.

Comment: Yes, i managed to fix it and now it works properly. The while loop never ended because of the BufferedReader. Apparently, it did nothing after it reached data i brought from the server was put in the answer string so the while loop never ended since there never was a null which should have ended a loop. Just changed the variable type that brought the server answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Message answer = null;
answer.obj=answer;
handler.sendMessage(answer);
```

which is guaranteed to fail with a `NullpointerException` (if you make it compile) try

```
handler.obtainMessage(0, answer).sendToTarget();
```